How to query the attributes/properties of a FeatureViewLayer in Earth Engine
NOTE I am asking about FeatureViews/FeatureViewLayers NOT FeatureCollections.
In the Earth Engine Code Editor, you can use the Inspector and click on a point on a FeatureView and see its properties.
But I cannot get that to work via code, such as the following:
// Define the FeatureView asset ID.
var assetId = 'WCMC/WDPA/current/polygons_FeatureView';

// Import the FeatureView asset as a FeatureViewLayer.
var layer = ui.Map.FeatureViewLayer(assetId);

// Add the FeatureViewLayer to the map.
Map.add(layer);

//Create a point to query
var point = ee.Geometry.Point([-105.67, 40.01]);

//show properties of the FeatureView/FeatureViewLayer at that location
layer.filterBounds(point).first().evaluate(function(result) {
  print(result.properties);
});

In the code editor Inspector, if I click that point I get the following properties pasted below, so that would seem to suggest they are somehow queryable.  Any idea how to do this?
The reason I ask is that since FeatureViewLayers are so much more performant than FeatureCollections, I was thinking they may be faster for querying properties as well.

Not Applicable DESIG: Wilderness Area DESIG_ENG: Wilderness Area
DESIG_TYPE: National GIS_AREA: 316.40157646838 GIS_M_AREA: 0 GOV_TYPE:
Federal or national ministry or agency INT_CRIT: Not Applicable ISO3:
USA IUCN_CAT: Ib MANG_AUTH: County Land ; Forest Service ; National
Park Service MANG_PLAN: Not Reported MARINE: 0 METADATAID: 1848 NAME:
Indian Peaks NO_TAKE: Not Applicable NO_TK_AREA: 0 ORIG_NAME: Indian
Peaks OWN_TYPE: State PARENT_ISO: USA PA_DEF: 1 REP_AREA:
316.035332426744 REP_M_AREA: 0 STATUS: Designated STATUS_YR: 1978 SUB_LOC: US-CO SUPP_INFO: Not Applicable VERIF: State Verified WDPAID:
370053 WDPA_PID: 370053 system:index: 002900000000000005fa


I had to reverse-engineer this from the HTTP calls the EE Code Editor makes when inspecting.
var features = ee.data.listFeatures(assetId, {
    region: point.toGeoJSONString(),
    filter: 'minVisibleLOD < 24'
  }
)

https://code.earthengine.google.com/ccd8051785b28cbb6d31a9f665fadbb8
I'm not sure what minVisibleLOD does exactly. The values are zoom levels though, between 0 and 24.
